# C++: int x[+30] is a valid declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization, operators

I have been studying arrays these days. I have come across a declaration of an array and initialization of its element in this manner :

```
int x[+30];
x[+1]=0;
```

This is confusing me a little. I have the concept in mind that when we write:

```
x[n]=0;
```

Then it means:

```
*(x+n)=0;
```

Then writing `x[+1]` would mean `*(x++1)` and this seems invalid. Please correct me for the mistake I am making in understanding this concept.

Comment: note, `*(x++1)` invalid because `++` is a increment operator, expression parsed as `*((x++)1)`

Comment: @utkarsh867: what is use of specifying array capacity explicitly to be +ve?

Comment: Note that `*(x + + 1)` **is** valid. The important rule here is that the transformation works at the **token** level, not the **character** level.

Comment: @rahul.deshmukhpatil As I explained in my answer, the extraneous `+` is simply acting as the Unary `+` operator.

Comment: @xirema: sorry, what I want to say is , array capacity is always going to be +ve at the time of definition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x[n]` means `*((x)+(n))` (note the blackets) and `x[+1]` means `*((x)+(+1))`. This is valid.

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.2.1 Subscripting

> The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))

Comment: Very fine blackets. I almost got the same ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikeCAT.

Answer (score 7):

The `+` Plus symbol can act as a Unary Operator. It usually has no effect, but the consequence is that it gets removed before the number is resolved. For example:

```
int x[+30];
```

Is converted to

```
int x[operator+(30)];
```

Which then becomes

```
int x[30];
```

Thus, this expression

```
x[+1] = 0;
```

Would simply resolve as

```
x[1] = 0;
```

It wouldn't resolve as *(x++1), especially since that's not valid syntax in c++.

Comment: I don't think unary plus is converted to `operator+` for an `int` argument, it's a built-in operator.

Comment: @TartanLlama For all intents and purposes, it's treated as such. You can write expressions like `int n = 8 + +9;` and the compiler will accept it and parse it as `8 + 9`.

Comment: But it has nothing to do with `operator+`, which is only considered if the argument is a class or enumeration type. The `+` operator is not the same thing as `operator+`.